# Selection issues with the hidden tag

Tags: selenium

I am unable to access the select option in this.

```
<tooltip-component params="id:'title1',title:'Alert name should be unique',isImportant:true"></tooltip-c
<br>
<select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Alert Type" id="alert_type" data-bind="options:alertType,optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id',chosenSelectedOptions: selected Alert,valueAllowUnset: true" ></select>
```

How can I make this drop list visible and accessible??

Comment: Use Id to access it

Answer (score 0):

You can use ID to locate it , try this code

```
    Select dropdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("alert_type")));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Value under Dropdown");.
```

You can also use xpath

```
    Select dropdown= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='alert_type']")));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Value under Dropdown");
```

Comment: TRY mines once and please share URL if possible

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the below mentioned answers.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("alert_type")));
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("alert_type"))).selectByVisibleText("Text Name Under Your Dropdown");
```

> OR

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("alert_type")));
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("alert_type"))).selectByIndex(0);  //Indexing start from zero
```

> OR

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("alert_type")));
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("alert_type"))).selectByValue("Value Name Under your Dropdown");
```

Comment: Thanks@Jainish. This is the response I get:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.31 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'

Comment: From your above mentioned error, try few seconds of wait before going to reach this element. So your driver may able to find the webelement. For wait use `Explicit wait` method. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: After try above solution, Still issue is not getting resolved then you may try this answer as well. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12141/selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-element-is-not-currently-visible

Comment: Also, Have you change the value `Text Name Under Your Dropdown`, Here you should provide, under the dropdown value name.

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your issue :)

Comment: Here's a additional information that  this uses a chosen plug in.

Comment: I didn't get you, what you are trying to say..Can you please provide you tried efforts??